# James Van Der Beek reference in "The Office" TV series

Tags: reference, the-office

In the 19th episode *(The Negotiation)* of season 3 of TV Series ***The Office***, Michael sees assistant of Jan and ask her "*Were you going to tell me that you hired James Van Der Beek.*" (time: 22:19)

I want to know why he said that. What is the reference behind this sentence?

Comment: Well, does the assistant look anything like James Van Der Beek?

Comment: The dude just looks like him...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I want to know why he said that.

Michael was just commenting on the fact that he thought Hunter was young and attractive.

> What is the reference behind this sentence?

It was a cultural reference to when James Van Der Beek played in *Dawson's Creek* during his youth years.